# Android sdk manager won't open Mac

Tags: android, terminal, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to double click the SDK Manager from the Android Studio window, but it won't open. I'm assuming it has something to do with path variables. I'm on Mac, and I don't know the commands to fix it.

Comment: What version of Android Studio? You can go to the Android SDK folder and start it from there.

Comment: I just downloaded it.

Comment: Android Studio, when you set it up, tells you where everything is installed.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

On Linux, **edit** your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file. Look for a line that sets the `PATH` environment variable and add the full path to the tools/ directory to it. If you don't see a line setting the path, you can add one: `export PATH=${PATH}:/tools`

On a Mac OS X, look in your home directory for `.bash_profile` and proceed as for Linux. You can create the `.bash_profile` if you haven't already set one up on your machine.
Should work.

Comment: I already have one  that says `export PATh=tools/` and `export PATH=platform-tools/`

Comment: Those don't look like the other PATH variables though, is there something wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

You may have dowloaded Android Studio w/o Android SDK.

It should be similar to intelliJ, so try this:
Download just a command line tool from here (scroll to the very bottom) [android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), it is zip file, unpack it.

With your project open - Open (or File\New\File if missing) local.properties file in your project and add this:

sdk.dir=/(path to folder where you unpacked)/android-sdk-macosx/

now Tools\Android\SDK Manager should start SDK Manager